# switch multiple words in 1 string with variable, python

Tags: python, string, cpu-word

```
class Cleaner:
    def __init__(self, forbidden_word = "frack"):
        """ Set the forbidden word """
        self.word = forbidden_word

    def clean_line(self, line):
        """Clean up a single string, replacing the forbidden word by *beep!*"""
        found = line.find(self.word)
        if found != -1 :
            return line[:found] + "*beep!*" + line[found+len(self.word):] 
        return line

    def clean(self, text):
        for i in range(len(text)):
            text[i] = self.clean_line(text[i])


example_text = [
        "What the frack! I am not going",
        "to honour that question with a response.",
        "In fact, I think you should",
        "get the fracking frack out of here!",
        "Frack you!"
        ]
```

Hi everyone, the issue with the following code, is the fact that when i run it, i get the following result:

```
What the *beep!*! I am not going
to honour that question with a response.
In fact, I think you should
get the *beep!*ing frack out of here!
Frack you!
```

On the second last line, one of the "frack" are not being changed.

I have tried using the if In line method but this doesn't work with variables. So how do i use an if statement that tracks a variable instead of a string? but also changes every word that needs changed?

PS. its exam practice i didn't make the code myself.

The expected outcome should be:

```
What the *beep!*! I am not going
to honour that question with a response.
In fact, I think you should
get the *beep!*ing *beep!* out of here!
Frack you!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `line.find(...)` will only return the first result, which you then replace with `"*beep!*"` and then return, thus missing other matches.

Either use [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) iteratively, passing in the appropriate `start` index each time until the start index exceeds the length of the line, or use Python's [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method to do all of that for you.

I'd recommend replacing:

```
found = line.find(self.word)
if found != -1 :
    return line[:found] + "*beep!*" + line[found+len(self.word):]
return line
```

with

```
return line.replace(self.word, "*beep!*")
```

Which will automatically find all matches and do the replacement.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explanation was great :D